# Foundation 6 sass breakpoint grid-column-collapse

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6, gutter

I am having a problem with my Foundation 6 scss code and need help.
I am trying to create the following code with Sass mixins.

```
<div class="row small-collapse medium-uncollapse large-collapse">
<div class="small-3 medium-6 large-3 columns bg-clip" style="background-color:yellow">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
</div>
<div class="small-3 medium-6 large-3 columns bg-clip" style="background-color:blue">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
```

So i have HTML

```
<style>
  .bg-clip {
    background-clip:content-box;
  }
</style>

<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box bg-clip" style="background-color:yellow">sass grid</div>
  <div class="box bg-clip" style="background-color:blue">sass grid</div>
</div>
```

And scss

```
.box-wrap {
  @include grid-row;
  .box {
    @include breakpoint(small) {
      @include grid-column(3);
      @include grid-column-collapse;
    }
    @include breakpoint(medium) {
      @include grid-column(6);
      @include grid-column-uncollapse(30);
    }
    @include breakpoint(large) {
      @include grid-column(3);
      @include grid-column-collapse;
    }
  }

}
```

Everything is working as expected but in breakpoint(large) grid-column-collapse wont work...

Thank you for your time

Comment: "Won't work" doesn't describe the problem.  What doesn't work here?  You get an error?  You get a different result than you expected?  It watches TV and collects welfare all day?

Comment: At breakpoint(large) i expect that column padding is removed with grid-column-collapse mixin but it is not.